# Unity InputSystem Action CallbackContext which key was pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm possible using this in the wrong way, but I have an InputSystem action (SelectPowerUp) that has three bindings for the keys 1,2 & 3.

This action is linked to a UnityEvent:

`public void SelectPowerUp(InputAction.CallbackContext context)`

How can I tell which key was pressed to invoke the event?  I don't want to create 3 different actions but I can't figure out how to pull the pressed key from the CallbackContext object.

Thanks
Mick

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@0.1/api/UnityEngine.Experimental.Input.InputAction.CallbackContext.html ?
It should be inside `context.control`.

Comment: I had, but it defaults to an InputControl which doesn't contain the KeyCode property.  However, cast that to a KeyControl and voila, the KeyCode property is available.

```var pressedButton = ((KeyControl)context.control).keyCode.ToString();```
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`context.control.name` return the name of the key you pressed. So for example:

```
public void DisplayStore(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
  Debug.LogWarning(context.control.name);
}
```

Will return 'escape' if you press the key escape , etc...